# Download error for us package (KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs')

Tags: python, anaconda

I can't download 'us' package after updating Anaconda. I am not used to python nor Terminal for Mac. The package used to run but after updating Anaconda, I can't import it on Spyder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Here's the error message:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1216): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in **call**
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
install(args, parser, 'install')
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 260, in install
unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 435, in _collect_all_metadata
_supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 202, in _supplement_index_with_system
archspec_name = get_archspec_name()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 212, in get_archspec_name
target_plat, target_arch = context.subdir.split("-")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1214, in print_unexpected_error_report
message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 237, in get_main_info_str
info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 260, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 435, in _collect_all_metadata
    _supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 202, in _supplement_index_with_system
    archspec_name = get_archspec_name()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 212, in get_archspec_name
    target_plat, target_arch = context.subdir.split("-")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

`$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda install us`

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
Timeout reached. No report sent.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as of very recently on my M1 Mac

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I figured it out after a bit of debugging.

There's a variable `conda` looks for called `subdir`, which indicates what architecture to get packages for.

If you run

```
conda config --show-sources
```

you can see a full list of all the sources setting different variables, and for me there's a variable called `subdir` being set to `***unset***`, which fails to get recognized when trying to split on `-` in the stack trace you got above (see `context.subdir.split("-")` in the last line).

For me the fix was to change the environment variable defining `CONDA_SUBDIR` as `***unset***`, and I did this by running

```
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64
```

This command will depend on your architecture and what exactly is setting the wrong value in `conda config --show-sources`. If you don't figure it out, post the results of that command and I'll see if I can parse it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. After running 'conda config --show-sources' on Terminal, 

channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

==> envvars <==
subdir: osx-arm64

I got this message. I can't find context.subdir.split("-") in the last line. Any help would be apprciated!